# Rotating the LookAt vector of gluLookAt

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm a student new to opengl. Currently, I'm doing a project that creates a scene.

Right now, my team is using `gluLookAt()` for my camera. What I want to accomplish is to try and rotate the `LookAt` vector around a certain point, namely where the camera is looking at.

This accomplishes a sort of "swaying in a circle". I need this because I am making a dart game for the scene, and my camera stay still, but I need it to move in a circle, but still allow the user's mouse to influence it. I also need it to create a drunken movement. That is why I am not considering rotating the `Up` or `Eye` vectors.

Currently, my look at code is like this.

```
int deltax = x - mouse.mX;
int deltay = y - mouse.mY;
cameradart.mYaw -= ((deltax/360.0) * 3.142) * 0.5;
cameradart.mPitch -= deltay * 0.02;
mouse.mX = x;
mouse.mY = y;
cameradart.lookAt.x = sin (cameradart.mYaw);
cameradart.lookAt.y = cameradart.mPitch ;
cameradart.lookAt.z = cos (cameradart.mYaw);
gluLookAt (cameradart.eye.x, cameradart.eye.y, cameradart.eye.z,
           cameradart.eye.x + cameradart.lookAt.x, cameradart.eye.y + cameradart.lookAt.y,
           cameradart.eye.z + cameradart.lookAt.z,
           cameradart.up.x, cameradart.up.y, cameradart.up.z);
```

I know that it could be done easier using a different camera, but I really don't want to mess with my team's code by not using `gluLookAt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of solutions in my mind, I'll tell you the easiest to understand/implement as a new graphics student

Assuming at first you're looking at (0,0,1) -store that vector-:

Think of a point that's drawing a circle and you're looking at it,

-Do it first to turn right and left (2D on X & Z)

-Let HDiff be the horizontal difference between old mouse position and the new one

-Update the x = cos(HDiff)

-Update the z = sin(HDiff)

*I didn't try it but it should work :)

Comment: Thanks! Question: Am I updating the lookAt of the x and z? That means that I would have cameradart.lookat.x = sin (cameradart.mYaw) * (cos HDiff). Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Well It looks like I made a mistake 
It's been so long,
referring to
[link]https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm

x' = x*cos(HDiff) - z*sin(HDiff), || ,
z' = z*cos(HDiff) + x*sin(HDiff)

Comment: One thing left, to understand the difference between what I wrote first and what I wrote as a comment:
first, You always calculate the new x & z from the origin, those the HDiff should represent how far the cursor is from the origin,
 || , The comment neglects the origin, it just keeps modifying the x & z without the need to store the origin

Comment: And replying to your question, no.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it after experimenting with it a bit. Always seem like when I just read something, I half get it. When I use something, I thoroughly get it.

Comment: That's exactly how it goes with mathematics :) Glad you got it :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to manipulate the camera, using a camera matrix is a much more effective mechanism than working with gluLookat.  GLM is a good library for matrix and vector math and includes a lookat mechanism you can use to initialize the matrix, or you can just initialize it with a series of operations.  However, remember that lookat produces a view matrix, and the view matrix is the *inverse* of the camera matrix.

[This piece](https://github.com/OculusRiftInAction/OculusRiftInAction/blob/master/source/Example_7_1_RenderScene.cpp) of code has a demonstration of what I'm talking about.  Specifically look at the player member variable and how it's manipulated

```
glm::mat4 player;

...

glm::vec3 playerPosition(0, eyeHeight, ipd * 4.0f);
player = glm::inverse(glm::lookAt(playerPosition, glm::vec3(0, eyeHeight, 0), GlUtils::Y_AXIS));
```

This approach lets you apply changes like rotation and translation directly to the player matrix

```
// Rotate on the Y axis
player = glm::rotate(player, angle, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
```

This is much more intuitive than manipulating the view matrix, since changes to the view matrix always have to be the inverse of what you'd do to the player matrix.

When you're ready to render you need to convert the player matrix to a view matrix by taking it's inverse.  In my example it's done like this:

```
gl::Stacks::modelview().top() = riftOrientation * glm::inverse(player);
```

This is because I'm using an application based modelview matrix stack that gets applied to the Shader programs I'm running.

For an OpenGL 1.x program, you'd instead use `LoadMatrix`

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glm::mat4 modelview = glm::inverse(player);
glLoadMatrixf(&modelview);
```